# How is it possible that CEWP shows up with IE but nothing in FF, Chrome and Safari?

Tags: jquery, content-editor-web-part

On my machine I can get CEWP to show (image and data) on IE and FF. Chrome and Safari still show nothing (just blank screen). CEWP is linking to a txt file that has javascript stuff. Here is the code if you want to see it in details (http://www.codeupload.com/4063).

Answer (score 2):

If the code you show in the link is what you've put into your CEWP, I'd expect problems. What you show is a full HTML page, including a BODY tag.  You should only include the markup you want. I think that will probably solve the issue.

So remove:

```
2.    <!DOCTYPE html>
3.    <html lang="en">
4.    <head>
5.        <meta charset="utf-8">  
6.        <title>Slides, A Slideshow Plugin for jQuery</title>
```

this

```
44.    </head>
45.    <body>
```

and the closing

```
105.    </body>
106.    </html>
```

Comment: Actually I have taken those tags out from the text file that I am feeding to CEWP.

Comment: Well, then it sort of hard to make an informed suggestion! I looked at what you had posted and that was my observation. If you could post what you actually have in your CEWP, I might have other ideas.